# What is the use of Composer.phar in php?

Tags: php, paypal, composer-php

Nowadays, I am found the lots of thing available but we should download and update the **composer.phar** and it will download something in apps and after that we can run the application. so what is the purpose of the **composer.phar** and why should it is required to **update**. any specific reason for that?

Yesterday, I have download the **PayPal Classic Library** for **PHP "MerchantAPI"** for **DoDirectPayment** purpose when I have configured but and run message given ***RUN "composer update"*** after I have download latest composer using **curl** and run `php composer.phar` update and it will download the **verndor** folder and other libraries inside for **paypal** and after I am able to run.

Please help me.

**EDIT:**
As per my thinking composer is more useful when dependencies required to our project.
For Instance:

PayPal has REST API
They will provide the API Library and Examples for different Web Services
Those web service access by using some Custom library given by PayPal like using CURL Based which will provide the number of Classes and Methods to use by us for access PayPal Libraries.

Suppose paypal has this Web service

PaymentWebService
 - Method1
 - Method2

So, they will provide the latest Library for that when we update the composer.

now suppose they added another method called - Method3
but we have not that 3rd Method include in our library but we can get this in our currenet library by using composer update ?

Am I right here????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#introduction) is a tool to manage dependencies in php. You were required to run `composer update` to download the libraries that the paypal library requires to run.

Comment: Please read the documentation first. If there are specific questions left, you can ask them here.